# How to exclude row from ag grid default filter

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

This is my codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-react-how-to-exclude-row-hm8x9?file=/README.md

- Type into any input box to filter by text

#### Question - how to exclude a row based upon its values from the instrinsic filter?

The return boolean from method isExternalFilterPresent - determines whether to run an additional filter - doesExternalFilterPass, not exclude existing filters applied.